# Eulerian orientations on connected countably infinite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a locally finite graph with $V$ countably infinite. Assume that each vertex has even degree. Does there necessarily exist an Eulerian orientation on $G$? That is, is there a way to direct the edges of $G$ so that the number of edges going into a vertex $v$ is same as the number of edges going out of $v$? I know that the answer is yes in the case of $2$-connected graphs as is mentioned here

[2-connected graph has a strongly connected orientation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197652/2-connected-graph-has-a-strongly-connected-orientation)

However, what if we drop the $2$-connectedness condition? That is, if we drop the property that $G$ is still connected upon the deletion of any one edge can we still find an Eulerian orientation?

Answer (score 0):

> 

"...can we [...] find an Eulerian orientation?" -- **YES**

A slightly more general result holds, as below (see the last ***Remark*** at the bottom
of this note).

> **ASSUMPTION**
>   (once and forever)

Let $\,G=(V\,E)\,$ be a locally finite graph such that every vertex has even degree.

> **THEOREM 1**

For every $\,e\in E\,$ there exists a positive $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ and an **injective**
map $\,\pi: \Bbb Z/n\to E\,$ such that $\,\pi(0)=e\,$ and

$$ \forall_{k\in\Bbb Z/n}\quad \pi(k)\,\subseteq\,\pi(k-1)\cup\pi(k+1) $$

In other words, $\,\pi\,$ is a finite cycle when $\,n>1,\,$ and $\,\pi\,$
is a path that is infinite in both directions when $\,n=1\,$ -- then
$\,\Bbb Z_1=\Bbb Z.$

**DEFINITION** A path $\,\pi\,$ as above is called an ***orbit***.  (*By
this definition, every orbit is non-empty*.)

> **THEOREM 2**

Let $\,H=(W\,F)\,$ be a graph such that $\,W\subseteq V\,$ and $\,F\subseteq E,\,$
and every vertex $\,w\in W\,$ has even degree in $\,H.\,$ Furthermore, let
$\,D\,:=\,E\setminus F\ne\emptyset\,$ and $\,U:=\bigcup D\,$ (so that
$\,U\subseteq V).\,$ **Then** there exists an orbit $\,\pi\,$ in graph $\,(U\,D).$

> **Proof** (of Theorem 2)

It's clear that every vertex $\,u\in U\,$ has even degree in graph
$\,(U\,D)\,$ (and $\,D\ne\emptyset).\,$ Thus, *Theorem 2* follows
from *Theorem 1*.

> **THEOREM 3**

Graph $\,G\,$ admits an Eulerian orientation.

> **Proof** (of Theorem 3)

By straightforward transcendental mathematical induction or by Kuratowski-Zorn
Theorem (also called Zorn Lemma), $\,E\,$ is a union of pairwise disjoint orbits.
Select either one of the two orientations for every orbit. This proves our *Theorem 3*.
  ***Great!***

> ***REMARK***   Theorem 3  holds for arbitrary cardinalities of $\,\,V$
>   and $\,E.\,$
>   (There is no need to assume that $\,V\,$ nor $\,E\,$ are infinite or countable).  Furthermore, if we assumed that every infinite cardinal number is even then we do not need to say anything about graph $\,B\,$ being locally finite.

**EDIT:**   @bof has wondered at one time about the non-local case. It takes only one extra consideration.

Let $\,S(v):=\{w\in V: {v\,w}\in E\subseteq E.\ $ Since every vertex $\,v\in E\,$ has even degree (finite or not) it means that there is a fixed-point free involution $\,i_v:S(v)\to S(v)\,$ for each $\,v\in V.\,$

Each time we start a new orbit by choosing $\,\pi(0)\in D\,$ we also choose
the orientation $\,(v^-\,v^+)\,$ of $\,\pi(0)=\{u\,w\},\,$ i.e.
$\,\{v^-\,v^+\}\,=\,\{u\,w\}.\,$ Now the whole orbit is determined uniquely by recursively defining new $\,\pi(n+1):=i_v(\pi(n))\,$ for
$\,v\in\pi(n)\,$ and $\,n>0\,$ but $\,v:=v^+\,$ for $\,n=0;\,$ and new
$\,\pi(n-1):=i_v(\pi(n))\,$ for $\,v\in\pi(n)\,$
and $\,n<0\,$ but $\,v:=v^-\,$ for $\,n=0;\,$.   ***Great!***

Comment: @bof, I've concentrated on the locally finite case but it takes very little extra to do also the general case of (possibly) infinite degrees. For each $\,v\in V\,$ let's fix a fixed point-free involution $\,i_v:S(v)\to S(v)\,$ of the star $\,S(v)\subseteq E.\ $ . Then we would choose orbits $\,\pi\ $ such that $\,\pi(k+1):=i_v(\pi(k))\,$ for $v\in\pi(k)\ $ or $\,\pi(k-1):=i_v(\pi(k))\,$ -- you make one decision about $\pm$ at $\,pi(0),\,$ and the rest of the orbit is uniquely determined after this.

Comment: @bof, I've extended my *Answer* -- thank you for prompting me to do so. :)